# Corporate Finance experiment, non-parametric test

Tags: statistical-significance, nonparametric, finance

I have an numerical, continous variable as my dependent variable, namely CDS. My independent variable is categorical, namely different time intervals after a downgrade.

Unfortunately my data does not have a normal distribution nor are the variances homogenous. Therefore I have to use a non-parametric test.

I want to show that the mean of my dependent variable for each category is significantly different from 0. So in the end I get more or less results like the ones in the simple table below.

```
        Interval 1     Interval 2     Interval 3     Interval 4     Interval 5     

 CDS             5*             6***           7**            5*             6
```

Which test do I have to use?

Comment: Do you have any idea what the distribution looks like, and if you could make it look more 'normal' through a transform like a logarithm?  That would be one approach.  Lots of data is not truly normal, but we go with close enough.

Comment: I tried it with logarithm as well as the square root, which did not really help. Both Shapiro-Wilk-Test and Levene Test showed that my data is not homogenous in its variances and not normally distributed. Even after said transformations.

Comment: CDS = credit default swap or something else? If it is credit default swap, what is the variable measuring -- some price of a CDS or some other aspect of it? WHat are the values in those intervals? Are they *counts*?

Comment: CDS stands for CDS-bond basis. It is a numerical value and stands for the change of the CDS-bond basis. The intervals are time intervals: "[-30,-1]", "[1,30]", "[31,60]", "[61,90]", "[1,90]", "[-1,1]", "[1,10]", where for example "[-1,1]" stands for the time interval from 1 day before and one day after the downgrade. "[1,90]" stands for the time interval from 1 day after to 90 days after the downgrade. Each time interval is a category. i would like to show the mean change of the CDS-bond-basis for each interval and whether it is statistically significant different from 0.

Answer (score 0):

What claims (even basic ones) can you make about the possible range of values or distribution?

If, for example, they can take on negative as well as positive values, and zero is sort of the 'expected' value (used a little loosely), then you probably already have it: the odds of five observations all lying on the same side of zero in that case is 1:32 which at least gives you 97% confidence they are all statistically above zero in a simple non-parametric test.

Comment: Ok I guess you're right. But don't you know a specific test I could do? I need to show my work in my paper.


    Min.      1st Qu.   Median     Mean  3rd Qu.     Max. 
-277.778  -13.433    1.970    4.903   19.476  235.460

Comment: Take a look at the sign test and related non-parametrics: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sign_test